# How to migrate only 1 index from ElasticSearch cluster to OpenSearch cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, search, migration, opensearch

I have a ElasticSearch cluster which has many indexes, and each index serves an independent purpose and is heavy size.

I have a OpenSearch Cluster and want to migrate only 1 index from the ES cluster to the OS cluster.

All the migration strategies from ES to OS i found on the internet migrates all the indexes. Migrating all the indexes will be a time consuming and redundant.

Is there a better way to migrate only 1 required index?

Answer (score 0):

You could set up manual snapshots to s3 and restore the specific index as below

`curl -XPOST 'domain-endpoint/_snapshot/my-snapshot-repo/2020-snapshot/_restore' -d '{"indices": "my-index"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'`

Note:
You need to register OS with same snapshot repo of ES for _restore to work and there will be little data loss between time of snapshot and restore commands run

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/managedomains-snapshots.html#managedomains-snapshot-restore